# Space homeomorphic to contractible space is contractible

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a contractible topological space and $Y$ is homeomorphic with $X$.

> How do I show that $Y$ is contractible?

Homeomorphic means there is an $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that there is a $g:Y\rightarrow X$ with $g\circ f$ is the identity on $X$.
Furthermore the identity on $X$ is nullhomotopic (because of contractibility).

Comment: Well, you can try and show that composing a retraction with a homeomorphism yields a retraction of $Y$...

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Why would that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $X$ homeomorphic to $Y$, there is a continuous invertible function $g:X\to Y$ s.t. $g^{-1}:Y\to X$ is also continuous.

Let $f:X\to X$ s.t. $x\mapsto x_0$ for some $x_0\in X$. Since $X$ contractible, there is a continuous function $H:X\times [0,1]\to X$ s.t. $H(x,0)=id_X(x)$ and $H(x,1)=f(x)$.

We will prove $id_Y$ is homeomorphic to $f':Y\to Y$ s.t. $y\mapsto g(x_0)$. Indeed, (as pointed out by @Riccardo) consider the function $H':Y\times [0,1]\to Y$ s.t. 
$$
H'(y,\lambda)=g(H(g^{-1}(y),\lambda))
$$
It is continuous as it is a composition of continuous functions. Also 
$$
H'(y,0)=g(H(g^{-1}(y),0))=g(g^{-1}(y))=id_Y(y)\\
H'(y,1)=g(H(g^{-1}(y),1))=g(x_0)=f'(y)
$$
Hence $Y$ is contractible.

Comment: Thanks for saving me the typework ;)

Comment: You are welcome : )